# In a custom Ruby class, how do you define the default representation of an instance?

Tags: ruby

I want an instance of my custom class to have the same methods and behavior as its superclass unless a specific method is invoked on it that returns something (like `next`, which returns the next `Numeric` in the sequence). It should act in this case like a `String`.

```
class MyNumber < Numeric
  ...
end

val = MyNumber.new(1)
# acts like a regular Numeric

val.next
#=> 2

val
#=> "Hello 2!"

puts "Hey #{val}"
#=> "Hey Hello 2!"
```

In the situation above, I guess I would just redefine `to_s`.

Comment: What doesn't work here?  is it "Hey #{val}"?  If that's it, what happens when you try it?

Comment: I'm not sure...it works in this case, but I was wondering about other contexts, such as output to a Rails view, but just didn't want to spin up a Rails app to try it out (though I'm assuming Rails erb would also just spit out the interpolated version).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the `inspect` method on that class. For example, if you modify `String#inspect` as:

```
class String
  def inspect; self * 2 end
end
```

then you get:

```
"Hello" # => "HelloHello"
```

I suppose you wanted this:

```
class MyNumber < Numeric
  def inspect; "Hey #{self}" end
end
```

Note that interpolation `"#{}"` uses `to_s` and not `inspect`, so this does not cause infinite recursion.

Comment: `inspect` is only for human-readable debugging output. Outside of IRb, it isn't used anywhere.

Comment: For only being used in IRB, it sure is found in a [lot of places](https://github.com/search?l=ruby&q=inspect&ref=cmdform&type=Code).